# Template class in std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

Is it possible to add a template class inside std::array without specifying the typename? I mean.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    ...
}

std::array<MyClass *> arr;
```

The reason is that I have a kind of storage that accepts all classes that derives from `MyClass` but the problem with the template class is that I need to specify the typename, then the class need to be like that:

```
class Storage
{
    ...
private:
    std::array<MyClass<TYPE GOES HERE> *> arr;
}
```

And I want something more or less like this:

```
class Storage
{
    ...
private:
    std::array<MyClass *> arr;
}
```

This way I can add any class that derives from MyClass.

Is there a way for doing that?

Comment: You mean like `template <typename> class T`?

Comment: I need to keep the template<typename T> but I want to create a storage with classes that derives from that class `MyClass`, but I can't do that because of the template, but I need to keep the template because I use it.

Comment: `MyClass` needs to be specialized for a concrete type to be actually instantiated: `MyClass<int>`.

Comment: One option is making `Storage` a template class as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I know, and that is the problem, I can't add another class in `std::array<MyClass<int>> arr;` if the template typename is different, understood? I want to be able to add any class that derives from `MyClass` independently of the template typename.

Comment: @Csq - But I will need to create a storage to each type. Isn't that a headache?

Comment: `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<double>` are completely unrelated types. If you want an array that can store pointers to both, give them a common base class or use type erasure.

Comment: `std::array<boost::any>`?

Comment: @T.C. - I know that they are different, but I'm talking about the class, that is the same and that others classes derives from (of course there's the template, but is the same class). I'm just wondering if there's a way for doing that.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm not using boost and I'm planning to, but I will check it out and maybe it can help me with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: There are no "template classes" in C++. There are only **class templates** - templates which can be used to produce classes. Templates (class templates) are not classes themselves ("You can't eat the cookie cutter" - STL)

Comment: If your code allows it you can create non template `MyBaseClass` and derive `MyClass` from it so that `Storage` will hold `std::array<MyBaseClass *> arr;`. If you need to call `T`-specific functions of `MyClass` from `Storage` - then you can't do this, and basically can't make `Storage` class non-`T`-specific.

Comment: There's no "derives from" here unless you give them one yourself. @dyp That's a nice quote. I gotta remember that.

Comment: " I'm just wondering if there's a way for doing that." Deriving from a common base **IS. THE. WAY.** Of doing "that".

Comment: @ArnonZilca - Yes, I use T inside of `MyClass`. - I think that the only "solution" that I can see is to create a storage with template as mentioned above.

Comment: @dyp - Nice quote, and I said "template class" because I thought was the same, no order for putting the words (my bad).

Comment: @MrAlmighty There's no problem with using `T` inside `MyClass`. The important thing is that `Storage`'s use of its array is `T`-free. This makes the inheritance idea possible.

Comment: @ArnonZilca - The storage will call methods from objects that is in the array. - I will avoid too much comments and try to code in here and see what I can do, anyway, you guys helped me already somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a base class from which `MyClass` derives and let the array store pointers to the base class.

```
struct MyBase
{
   virtual ~Base() {}
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass : public MyBase
{
    ...
}

std::array<MyBase*> arr;
```

Comment: Despite others members helped me and some of them (such as the answer below), mentioned that technique, and yes, it worked and seems to be the best. The only thing is that to use methods of classes that derives from `MyClass` is that I need to declare on `MyBase` before. Polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason is that I have a kind of storage that accepts all classes that derives from MyClass

You cannot create a class that derives from `MyClass`, you can create a class that derives from `MyClass<int>` for example etc. So solutions that I see are:

- Make template `MyClass` derived from non template `BaseClass` and keep pointer to `BaseClass`
- Make `MyClass` non template and create a template class that derives from it. (this is technically the same as the first)
- Keep `void *` and cast it to specific `MyClass<>` on usage, this is error prone though and not recommended.
- Use `boost::any` or `boost::variant` (using `boost::variant` would be pretty complicated though